# Why am I getting a warning of not having a unique key?

Tags: reactjs

This is my render

```
render() {
    let products = this.state.products  
    return (
      <ul>
        {products.map((product, index) => Product({ key: index, product: product }))}          
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

I am using a unique key, and still get the warning

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"
>   prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you return a `Component` or pass it the key prop (or any other props...)

```
<ul>
    {products.map((product, index) => (
        <Product key={index} product={product} />
    ))}
</ul>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#composing-components

Comment: Does it matter if `Product` is a functional component? Those should accept props in as a parameter?

Comment: The [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) (See `Welcome()`) say otherwise. And I just make a plunk that showed that OP's syntax is fine :(

Comment: @HPierce We are talking about 2 different things.... Product can be a functional component and receive the props as the docs suggest... But passing the props to that functional component is as I pointed out... Look at the docs again...

Comment: @SakoBu I read you could do it both ways https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965309/react-functional-component-calling-as-function-vs-as-component

Comment: It's not new and I encourage you to do some research about the limitations of it... https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f (go down into the comments....)

Comment: Also, in a 'real-world' app you should never use the index as the key...

Comment: @SakoBu "Also, in a 'real-world' app you should never use the index as the key." why not

Comment: Let me rephrase that... if they the array is never going to change then it's fine but if you remove an element from the array (most real-world apps and use cases) then you can see how the index as a key would get messed up... @user3808307

Answer (score 1):

I found this for you.

[How to create unique keys for React elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549424/how-to-create-unique-keys-for-react-elements)

It seems like you need to have a return for the key.
Or, as it states, npm packages already exist to declare unique keys.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing child elements to the `ul`

```
render() {
    let products = this.state.products  
    return (
      <ul>
        {products.map((product, index) => 
          <li key={index}>
            {product}
          </li>}          
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

Comment: So there is no way to not get the warning when calling the component as a function then? I will always get the warning? That shouldn't be so, because then I am forced to not to, which supposedly is ok

Comment: The <li> part is in the Product component, I am not supposed to change it

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this:

```
function Product(props) {
  return (
     <p key={props.key}>{props.product}</p> 
  )
}

function Main(props) {
  let products = [ "foo", "bar", "baz"];
  return (
    <ul>
      {products.map((product, index) => Product({key: index, product: product }))}        
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main></Main>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

and this:

```
function Product(props) {
  return (
     <p>{props.product}</p> 
  )
}

function Main(props) {
  let products = [ "foo", "bar", "baz"];
  return (
    <ul>
      {products.map((product, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          {Product({product: product })}
        </li>
      ))}    
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main></Main>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Do what you're trying to accomplish.

**If I had to guess** (I don't have high confidence in this explanation), I would suspect that React requires a `key` prop on child components to so that it can quickly determine which elements need to be re-rendered when state changes. Therefore, passing a `key` prop won't actually achieve anything unless it's actually rendered as UI. The two examples above are rendering keys to the virtual DOM in the `<p>` and `<li>` respectively.

Comment: I will try this, thank you, i will have to repeat the key though, because I need it as a prop in the Product component
Edit: I can't do this, because the <li> is already on Product, and it is a test, that part I cannot touch.