# <Comp /> vs {Comp()} or even {Comp}: why extra React internal nodes for nothing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, jsx, lifecycle

I have lots of simple React functional components like these:

```
const Icon = (p:{icon:string}) => <i className={'fas fas-'+icon}/>
const Foo = () => <div>test1 <p>test2</p></div>
const X = () => (
  <div>
    <Foo />
    <Icon icon='test' />
  </div>
)
```

In my codebase, most of those use `memo()`, or are wrapped in `mobx-react-lite`'s `observer()` that itself add `memo()`

This is how mostly everyone seems to do it, but I think this is much better in most scenarios:

```
const icon = (icon:string) => <i className={'fas fas-'+icon}/>
const foo = <div>test1 <p>test2</p></div>
const X = () => (
  <div>
    {foo}
    {icon('test')}
  </div>
)
icon
```

because I see really few reasons to create those extra react internal DOM nodes, and pay the price for all lifecycle events, etc.

sure, `React.createElement` helps with:

- managing complex scenario (`useEffect`, state, error boundaries etc.)
- provides facilities with props
- gives a pretty names in the tree
- ...

but in most cases, it is not needed. What I see everywhere is people creating more nodes than needed, then adding even more wrappers around to try make React do as little as possible and, in the process, they obfuscate their code (writing component names twice because of JSX, adding useless function, syntax, etc.).

In my examples above, I see NO reason besides prettier name in component tree, and I'm pretty sure I could just find a way to provide the name for cheap.

Why do people always write things like `A1` & `B1` when `A2` & `B2` are simpler, faster, better, more logical in lots of scenarios?

```
const A1 = () => <div />
const B1 = () => <div><A1 /></div>

const A2 = <div />
const B2 = <div>{A2}</div>
```

the generated code is:

```js
var A1 = function A1() { return React.createElement("div", null); };
var B1 = function B1() { return React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement(A1, null)); };

var A2 = React.createElement("div", null);
var B2 = React.createElement("div", null, A2);
```

Here is a prior question on SO I found but answer seems quite incomplete to me.

- [React Functional component: calling as function vs. as component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965309/react-functional-component-calling-as-function-vs-as-component)
- https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f

What I am missing/not understanding?