# ReactJS: Difference between functional component and a function which returns jsx

Tags: reactjs

Consider the below function

```js
function DummyComponent() {
   return (
      <div class='dummy'>
       <p> Hello world </p>
      </ div>
   )
}
```

Now DummyComponent can be used in two ways to render

> Method 1:

```js
<DummyComponent />
```

> Method 2

```js
<>
  {DummyComponent()}
</>
```

What is the difference between the two considering both get the job done?
Are there any advantages or disadvantages for either of the two methods?

Comment: code snippets will not run, just used them so the code looks neater.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Functional component: calling as function vs. as component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965309/react-functional-component-calling-as-function-vs-as-component)

Answer (score 1):

Method 2 is much fast, for further details, please go through link below.

https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f