# How to we achieve code-reuse if we use React Redux Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, code-reuse

Let's say we have a component:

```js
function Count() {
  const count = useSelector(state => state.count);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const increment = () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' });
  const decrement = () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' });

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increment}> + </button>
      {count}
      <button onClick={decrement}> - </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

suppose it actually is a complicated component, and instead of 3 lines of code inside the `return ()`, there are 45 or 80 lines of code.  In that case, how do we achieve code-reuse if we don't want to repeat the code if we need to map this component to a different Redux state?

For example,

1. what if we need two such components on the same page, one for `countIceCream` and one for `countDrink`?
2. if on the To Go Order page, we need such component but it is for `countSpoon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I will do is 
make two components , the **First** `IceCreamCount` or `DrinkCount`  and the second is basic `Count` component which will not be connected to redux

example :

```
function Count(props){
     return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.increment}> + </button>
      {props.count}
      <button onClick={props.decrement}> - </button>
    </div>
  );
}


//connected to redux
function IceCreamCount(props){
    return <Count count={props.count} increment={...} decrement={...} />
}
```

Comment: interesting... what if passing those not by component by just a regular function? Something like `return Count(count, increment, decrement);`

Comment: checkout this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965309/react-functional-component-calling-as-function-vs-as-component

Comment: are you saying I could?  by the way I also was thinking: if the Count() simply returns a function that can return JSX, and IceCreamCount() does those useSelector() and then invoke Count() to get back a function to spit out the JSX

Comment: Yep you could . give it a try

Comment: I tried both ways, and they worked. Then `IceCreamCount()` feels like a container... actually `IceCreamCount()` doesn't take `props` and it takes nothing... and sets up using `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()`... and then use the generic (presentational) `<Count ... />`  I also tried the other method of using and calling `Count()` as a JS function and it works too

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to produce the same output but get the state data from different places for CountIceCream and CountDrink. Also the actions are different for CountIceCream and CountDrink.

So here is an example for increment action for CountIceCream and CountDrink:

```
const incrementDrink = ()=>({type;INCREMENT_DRINK})
const incrementIceCream = ()=>({type;INCREMENT_ICE_CREAM})
```

Here are the selectors to get count data for drink and ice cream (this is a simple example, in projects I would advice using [composable selectors](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/react-redux-hooks/blob/master/src/selectors.js) to prevent duplication)

```
const selectIceCreamCount = state => state.iceCream.count;
const selectIceDrinkCount = state => state.drinkCream.count;
```

Your container can look something like this:

```
const CounterContainer = function CounterContainer(
  { selector, up, down, remove },
  props
) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const count = useSelector(selector);
  const propsForPresentational = {
    count
    increment: () => dispatch(incement),
    decrement: () => dispatch(decrement),
    ...props,
  };
  //a container should not return jsx, 
  //  better create a presentational component instead      
  return <div>bunch of jsx</div>
};
```

Here is how you can create an ice cream count container:

```
export const IceCreamCountContainer = React.memo(
  function IceCreamCountContainer(props) {
    return CounterContainer(
      {
        selector: selectIceCreamCount,
        increment:incrementIceCream,
        decrement:decrementIceCream,
      },
      props
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: what is in `SpoonCounter.js` and `ForkCounter.js`? So to use another counter we need another file for that counter and also come here to add that `AnotherCounter` here in this file?

Comment: so I was saying what if `Count` needed 45 or 80 lines of code. So your SpoonCounter and ForkCoutner each needs 45 lines of code repeated?

Comment: @nonopolarity So you have same jsx but different actions and selectors?

Comment: what? I am saying how to avoid have the same JSX one more time. Do you understand what the question is?

Comment: @nonopolarity I updated my answer, not sure if I got it right this time but think your counters all get `count` somewhere from state and can dispatch `increment` and `decrement` actions. A counter can be a IceCreamCounter or DrinkCounter that look the same but will dispatch different increment and decrement actions and show different `count`

Comment: looks a little complicated and on the whim...  I was hoping there is a standard or common pattern... or one simpler one might be... if the `Count()` simply returns a function that can return JSX, and `IceCreamCount()` does those `useSelector()` and then invoke `Count()` to get back a function to spit out the JSX