# React hooks: call component as function vs render as element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Say we have component:

```
let Component = (props)=><div>Hi</div>;
```

I have sometimes come across code where someone *calls a react component as function* in render:

```
 const App = () => (
     <div> {Component()} </div>
 )
```

vs *rendering it as element*

```
 const App = () => (
     <div> <Component/> </div>
 )
```

In react hooks, what can go wrong if I *call component as function*?

---

There is [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965309/react-functional-component-calling-as-function-vs-as-component) question but it is not specifically targeted at hooks  - also that question is more about performance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here are some things which can happen if you *call component as function* vs *rendering it as element*.

1. **Potential violation of rules of hooks**

When you *call a component as a function* (see `TestB()` below) and it contains usage of hooks *inside it*, in that case react thinks the hooks *within* that function belongs to the *parent* component. Now if you conditionally render that component (`TestB()`) you will violate one of the [rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) of hooks. Check the example below, click the re-render button to see the error:

> Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an
> accidental early return statement.

```js
 
function TestB() {
  let [B, setB] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setB(B + 1);
      }}
    >
      counter B {B}
    </div>
  );
}
 

function App() {
  let [A, setA] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setA(A + 1);
        }}
      >
        re-render
      </button>
      {/* Conditionally render TestB() */}
      {A % 2 == 0 ? TestB() : null}
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Now you can use `<TestB/>` instead and see the difference.

2. **[Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) might not work as expected**

When you render a react component as react element say `<TestB/>` and then on next render you render some different component `<TestC/>` instead of it (in the same place in component hierarchy), due to reconciliation algorithm (and since *component type has changed*),  react will unmount `<TestB/>` component (all its state will be gone)  and mount a new component `<TestC/>` instead.

If you call it as function however (e.g. `TestB()`), the *component type*  will not participate in reconciliation anymore and you might not get expected results:

```js
function TestB() {    
  return (
    <div     
    >
      <input/>
    </div>
  );
}
function TestC() {
  console.log("TestC")
  return (
    <div     
    >
      <input/>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  let [A, setA] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setA(A + 1);
        }}
      >
        re-render
      </button>
      {/*  Here we are alternating rendering of components */}
      {A % 2 == 0 ? TestB() : TestC()} 
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <div id="react"></div>
```

- Type something in the input
- Now click the re-render button
- You can see now from the log that component `TestC` was rendered, but the input shows the same value you typed before - which might not be what you want as  you rendered a different component. This happened because reacts reconciliation algorithm couldn't detect that we moved to a *different* component (from `TestB` to `TestC`) and didn't remove previous input instance from DOM.

Render these components as elements now (`<TestB/>` and `<TestC/>`) to see the difference.