# React.memo vs useMemo for private components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Imagine you have a component expecting a function that renders a specific subtree in that component's hierarchy:

```
const Timeline = ({ renderDetails, ... }: { renderDetails: (rowData, sectionID, rowID) => React.Node }) => <div>{renderChildren(...)}</div>;
```

Is there a difference in using:

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(({ someProp }) => <someComponentHierarchyHere>...</someComponentHierarchyHere>);

const ParentComponent = ({ someProp }) => {
    const renderChildren = useCallback(() => <MyComponent someProp={someProp} />, [someProp]);

    return <Timeline renderChildren={renderChildren} />;
};
```

vs

```
const ParentComponent = ({ someProp }) => {
    const MyComponent = useMemo(({ someProp }) => <someComponentHierarchyHere>...</someComponentHierarchyHere>);
    const renderChildren = useCallback((rowData, sectionID, rowID) => <MyComponent someProp={someProp} />, [someProp]);

    return <Timeline renderChildren={renderChildren} />;
};
```

or simply:

```
const ParentComponent = ({ someProp }) => {
    const renderChildren = useCallback((rowData, sectionID, rowID) => <someComponentHierarchyHere>...</someComponentHierarchyHere>, [someProp]);

    return <Timeline renderChildren={renderChildren} />;
};
```

? I'm specifically interested in the decisions React renderer will take, as well as whether the `MyComponent` component (or the hierarchy it inserts in the component tree) will be memoized.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference, you'd rather create a separate component as in your first example with separate ```MyComponent``` with React.memo, than creating in inside ```ParentComponent```. When creating it inside ```ParentComponent```, React will have to check in every render, whether ```MyComponent``` is updated and if yes it will use more cost to update it.

Comment: Don't create components inside components, that's a bad pattern that can mess up the reconciliation process since you are re-creating the instance. If you still want to do it, remember to only create it once (empty array of dependencies that you haven't put).

Comment: why you need `useCallback` is unclear, it is useful when you want to pass the memoized callback to a component wrapped in `memo`, `Timeline` isn't wrapped in `memo`; fyi: also calling react components as functions have some [gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69432301/react-hooks-call-component-as-function-vs-render-as-element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, component definitions should always be static, so `React.memo` is the correct option here.

If your inner component is completely stateless, `useMemo` will appear to work, but you won't be able to use any hooks inside of the inner component, so for anything complex, you would have to do it the other way anyhow.

The reason for this is that, internally, React keeps track of what component is rendering at any given time, and that's how it determines what values are returned by `useState` and other hooks. Note that you're not using a dependencies array in your `useMemo`, meaning that it will be recreated on every render, so it's effectively pointless (the react hooks linting rules will warn you about this. However, even with an empty dependencies array, it still would not be safe to use hooks in it. A common misconception is that is `useMemo` with no dependencies will create a constant, but this is not the case. It's an optimization that **usually** prevents recalculation of values, but it's not guaranteed. Internally, React can choose to discard the memoized result of `useMemo` at any time. If that happened, it would randomly discard your state, so React prohibits it entirely.

```js
import { useMemo, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const MyComponent = useMemo(() => {
    // This line errors:
    // React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback.
    // React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a
    // custom React Hook function. (react-hooks/rules-of-hooks) eslint
    const [input, setInput] = useState('')
  
    return (
      <input value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.text)} />
    )
  })

  return <MyComponent />;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Both have a similar name and are optimization methods. But that's where the similarity ends, they're totally distinct React features.

`React.memo` is for when you find an existing component that is expensive to render, and you don't have the option to optimize it internally. Just wrap it and let React do an extra check.

`React.useMemo` is for internally optimizing a component by saving the return value of an expensive function call.

### Implementation

#### `useMemo`

The [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a8c9cb18b7e5d9eb3817272a1260f9f6b79815a2/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.new.js#L1914-L1915) is relatively straightforward. The previous value is returned if the deps didn't change.

```
const prevDeps: Array<mixed> | null = prevState[1];
if (prevState !== null) {
    if (areHookInputsEqual(nextDeps, prevDeps)) {
        return prevState[0];
    }
}

const nextValue = nextCreate();
hook.memoizedState = [nextValue, nextDeps];
return nextValue;
```

In all other cases it calls the (supposedly expensive) `nextCreate` function. The result is first saved in the hook log (for use in next renders) and then returned.

For the initial ("mount") render, React uses a [simpler implementation](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a8c9cb18b7e5d9eb3817272a1260f9f6b79815a2/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.new.js#L1898) that just calls `nextCreate`, saves it, and returns it.

#### `React.memo`

`React.memo` is quite a different type of function. It's a sort of Higher Order Component, but with a catch. It doesn't return a regular React component, but [a special `REACT_MEMO_TYPE`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/49f8254d6dec7c6de789116e20ffc5a9401aa725/packages/react/src/ReactMemo.js#L26). This type ultimately results in special handling of these elements while executing render work.

There's more moving parts to this but for the sake of simplicity I just copied [the props check](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d54880d4241aab772e6e2e6aedbb7176b9f2c191/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberBeginWork.new.js#L550-L552).

```
let compare = Component.compare; // This is what you pass into 2nd argument.
compare = compare !== null ? compare : shallowEqual;

if (compare(prevProps, nextProps) && current.ref === workInProgress.ref) {
  return bailoutOnAlreadyFinishedWork(current, workInProgress, renderLanes);
}
```

Unlike `useMemo` it doesn't involve storing any additional state. Instead the comparison function is used to avoid calling the (supposedly expensive) render function. It simply aborts a chunk of work before starting it, when it sees it would be useless.

### Conclusion

These are really 2 distinct things with a similar name and purpose.

### Applicability to OP use case

You'll probably want `React.memo`.

*Of course you always **first measure** if there's anything to optimize at all. Each of these things has a cost on its own. You can't sprinkle it around and automatically gain performance. If it's not balanced by avoiding expensive tasks, it's only making the code slower and more complex.*

The following doesn't do anything useful:

```
useMemo(({ someProp }) => <someComponentHierarchy>...</someComponentHierarchy>)
```

If you check the React source above, you see the `nextCreate` function is called without arguments.

Regardless of what you put in it, `useMemo` will not result in the same check for the Memoized element type as `React.memo` does, so it can't be used for the same purpose.