# Will this method of rendering jsx affect my app performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I noticed when i do console.log("testing") in Test() function, it will keep repeating  logs. With this, i'm wondering if it using this method to render Jsx will affect my app performance assuming i have many of them.

```
Test = ()=>{
      if(condition){
        return<Text>Coming Soon</Text>
       }else{
       return null;
       }
    }


render() {
return (
  <View> 
    {
    [1,2,3,4].map(list=>
      this.Test()
      )
 }
  </View>
);
```

}

Comment: Does it gives you too many re-renders error ?

Comment: this depend where you console log.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965309/react-functional-component-calling-as-function-vs-as-component, but it has some pitfalls in hooks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69432301/react-hooks-call-component-as-function-vs-render-as-element?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MridulGupta it doesnt give me error. But the console.log i do in Test() keeps logging.. That's why i'm wondering if it will affect the performance even without any console.log in Test() method

Comment: @MohitSharma I console.log() in Test() method as shown above. If i dont console log, obviously there wont be any long or continuous log

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I'm actually not comparing etween calling as function or jsx component. Instead i'm trying to know the performance implications when conditionally use a method to render a react component. Thanks for the link you sent

Comment: @OnweStephen how many time you see console log? it is more than 4 time.

Comment: Infinity... once i add console.log in Test() method.
It logs every 1 second