# Can I store a component in a variable and push children to it after it has been created?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Let's say that I have this component:

```
const Test = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    return <>{children}</>
};

export default Test;
```

I am wondering if it is possible to create a variable that holds the component like this:

```
const test = <Test></Test>;
```

And then loop over some data and push children to the `test` variable on every iteration.

Comment: Would rendring `<Test>{arr.map(...)}</Test>` work? You would push to `arr` (well not push since that mutates `arr`, but concat to it), and then withinn the `.map()` you would return JSX

Comment: @NickParsons No, at the time of initialization of the test variable, I won't have access to the array of children elements, which is why I'm trying to push them after the component has been created.

Comment: The idea is that `arr` would initially be empty, so it wouldn't be rendering anything. It's only once you have the items you need would you update the `arr` state, which would cause your component to rerender with the child elements

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have the data yet, then all you have to do is conditionally render your component when you *do* have the data.

```
{ data ? (<Test>{data.map(...)}</Test>) : <SomeOtherComponent /> /* or null */}
```

or

```
{ data ? <>{data.map((x) => <Test>{x}</Test>)}</> : <SomeOtherComponent /> /* or null */}
```

depending on what you want achieve, i didn't fully understand your question

i.e. if you have the data you need, render the component, rendering the children as you see fit, otherwise render some other component (or null, to render nothing)

Answer (score -1):

Yeap, try that pattern:

```
const test = (children) => <Test>{children}</Test>;
```

and usage

```
<>
{[1,2,3].map(el=>test(el))}
</>
```

[Edited]

```
const TestComp = ({children}) => <Test>{children}</Test>;

<>
{[1,2,3].map(el=>(<TestComp>{el}</TestComp>))}
</>
```

Comment: no, do not call a component as a function, render it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69432301/react-hooks-call-component-as-function-vs-render-as-element